# new rows in dataframe based on value in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a text file and need to convert it to excel in python.
The format is as follows

```
 edit "abcdef"                                                             
    set animal "tiger"                                                
    set wild-animal tiger                                             
    set tameanimal horse cow                                          
    set bird eagle                                                                             
    set bug "ant"                                                    
 next                                                                                                                          edit "fveafs"                                                             
    set animal "bear"                                                                                
    set wild-animal lion                                                  
    set tameanimal sheep turtle                                                        
    set bird dove                                                                 
    set bug "spider"                                                          
   next
```

I want the word after set to be the column headers, and the rest should be rows

```
title   animal   wild-animal   tameanimal       bird     bug                                       
abcedf   tiger    tiger         horse cow      eagle     ant                               
 fveafs   bear    lion          sheep turtle   dove      spider
```

Comment: It would have been far easier if you could just show us your sample data and code?

Comment: security reasons.. different ip addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a "script" like that to a list of dictionaries can be done with something like this. (It works for the subset of data you've pasted, but for a larger dataset, who knows.) Things might get tricky if there ever is an `edit` line with a different quoting, or whatever...

Turning the list of dictionaries into a Pandas dataframe or whatever else you need is left as an additional exercise to the reader.

```
import ast
import io
import shlex
from pprint import pprint


def parse_script(in_data):
    out_data = []
    row = None

    for line in in_data:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        verb, _, rest = line.partition(" ")
        if verb == "edit":
            row = {"title": ast.literal_eval(rest)}
            out_data.append(row)
        elif verb == "set":
            bits = shlex.split(rest)
            column = bits.pop(0)
            row[column] = bits
        elif verb == "next":
            row = None
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown verb {verb} in line {line}")
    return out_data


in_data_text = """
edit "abcdef"
    set animal "tiger"
    set wild-animal tiger
    set tameanimal horse cow
    set bird eagle
    set bug "ant"
next
edit "fveafs"
    set animal "bear"
    set wild-animal lion
    set tameanimal sheep turtle
    set bird dove
    set bug "spider"
next
"""

with io.StringIO(in_data_text) as fp:  # could be `open("script.txt") as fp`
    out_data = parse_script(fp)

pprint(out_data)
```

The output here is

```
[{'animal': ['tiger'],
  'bird': ['eagle'],
  'bug': ['ant'],
  'tameanimal': ['horse', 'cow'],
  'title': 'abcdef',
  'wild-animal': ['tiger']},
 {'animal': ['bear'],
  'bird': ['dove'],
  'bug': ['spider'],
  'tameanimal': ['sheep', 'turtle'],
  'title': 'fveafs',
  'wild-animal': ['lion']}]
```